# Reduce vertical space between 2 rows in a table HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with multiple rows, for example five rows. I need to reduce the gap between the third and fourth rows.

Below is my code:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Row</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second Row</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Third Row</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fourth Row</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
```

The result is

> First 1
>
> Second 2
>
> Third 3
>
> Fourth 4

I want to remove the gap between the third and fourth rows as below:

> First 1
>
> Second 2
>
> Third 3
>   
>   Fourth 4

Is it possible to set the padding between third and fourth row only to 0? to reduce the gap between them?

Comment: So what you actually mean is, you want the contents of rows 3 and 4 to be displayed side by side, correct? Would the combined contents of rows 3 and 4 be the same as the widths of either row 1 or row 2?

Comment: No it wont be of the same widths, it can vary.  rows 3 and 4 will below each other but no gap in between them, padding or margin should be zero.

Answer (score 8):

It's worth noting that the space can be reduced by collapsing the table's borders:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

You could do something similar to what Jukka K. Korpela [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18882932/2680216), and set padding on all the elements except the last `tr` child using a combination of the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)/[`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo classes.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p54rJ/)

```
tr:not(:last-child) td {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

The above example works in your instance, however the targeted element may not be the last element. You could therefore use the [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo class to target the desired element.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q8N7C/)

```
tr td {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
tr:nth-child(4) td {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

As you can see, this approach works when you have more elements:

[image]

Comment: Now that I’ve edited the question to reveal the intended formatting, this answer is not what the asker wants. It seems he wants the vertical space between rows to be decreased, rather than the rows to be put horizontally next to each other.

Comment: It was an accurate edit. If you look at [the Markdown source of the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32b3fdcf-0fba-4354-94dc-e1af4c56dc60/view-source), you can see that the asker wrote the fourth row *below* the third row, not next to it. It is [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) that combined the lines of text. If the asker actually wanted the the rows combined, he would have written them that way; thus he was probably just unfamiliar with Markdown, and didn't notice that his formatting was messed up. Can I revert the question back?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear on my question, Rory O'Kane was right. I wanted the vertical space between the two rows to be reduced.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you use special settings in HTML, there will be just a couple of pixels between rows of a table. If you really want to remove that, the simplest way is to use

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
```

and then set padding as desired, in CSS, on individual cells, e.g. with

```
tr:not(:last-child) td { padding-top: 4px }
```

Comment: I have many rows in the column and i would have to set padding for individual cells. Is there a way to set the padding of a particular row in a table to 0.

Comment: @user2480288, yes, but you need to specify which row in which context, and you should either clarify this by editing your question, not just in a comment, or post a new question.